# How to change the size of the icon in a Tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter, icons

I have an image which size is 304x105 (more wide than tall) but when I add it as a **icon in my Tkinter application is shrinks and cannot be seen properly**:

[image: Top left side of the application you can see some words that are illegible]

This is what I have written so far (related with the icon)

```
  def set_icon(self):
        img = tk.Image("photo", file="icon.gif")
        self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, img)
```

Comment: Do you want it bigger or smaller?

Comment: I would it to be bigger. However right now it seems to be an square, when the original picture is a rectangle size (304x105 pixels), so I would like to modify the scales in each axis, not just the total scale of the picture (And if making the whole pic bigger is the only solution then I am happy with that)

Comment: Try using an image editing application to resize the image to the required size.  But I think the result is more or less the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well I also faced this kind of problem I think you should try:
Pls upvote new user

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
resized_image= img.resize((300,205), Image.ANTIALIAS)
new_image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
```